# lme4 random effect structure with dredge

Tags: r, mixed-models

I have constructed an `lme4` model for model selection in `dredge` but I am having trouble aligning the random effects with the relevant fixed effects.The structure of my full model is as follows.

```
fullModel<-glmer(y ~x1 + x2 + (0+x1|Year) + (0+x1|Country) + (0+x2|Year) + (0+x2|Country) + (1 | Year) +(1|Country), family=binomial('logit'),data = alldata)
```

In this model structure, model selection in `dredge` produces three combinations of fixed effects, i.e. x1, x2, and x1+x2, however the random effect structure remains the same as in the full model, such that even when fixed effect is only x1, the random effect will include `(0+x2|Year) + (0+x2|Country)`. For example the model with only x1 as the fixed effect, will still have x2 within the random effects structure as follows.

```
y ~x1 + (0+x1|Year) + (0+x1|Country) + (0+x2|Year) +(0+x2|Country) + (1 | Year) +(1|Country), family=binomial('logit')
```

Is there a way to configure `dredge` not to select random effects that have other fixed effects specified in them? I have about x1….x50.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do that out-of-box as `dredge` currently omits all `(x|g)` expressions, but you can make a "wrapper" around (`g`)`lmer` that replaces the "|" terms in the formula with something else (e.g. `re(x,g)`), so that `dredge` thinks these are fixed effects. Example:

```
glmerwrap <-
function(formula) { 
    cl <- origCall <- match.call()
    cl[[1L]] <- as.name("glmer") # replace 'lmerwrap' with 'glmer'
    # replace "re" with "|" in the formula:
    f <- as.formula(do.call("substitute", list(formula, list(re = as.name("|")))))
    environment(f) <- environment(formula)
    cl$formula <- f
    x <- eval.parent(cl) # evaluate modified call
    # store original call and formula in the result:
    x@call  <- origCall
    attr(x@frame, "formula") <- formula
    x
}
formals(glmerwrap) <- formals(lme4::glmer)
```

Following `example(glmer)`:

```
# note the use of re(x,group) instead of (x|group)
(fm <- glmerwrap(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period +
    re(1, herd) +  re(1, obs), family = binomial, data = cbpp))
```

Now,

```
dredge(fm)
```

manipulates both fixed and random effects.

Comment: This is a great work around and it has worked for me. I need to reduce the number of un necessary combinations. In your example, I tried to keep only the models containing both 'fixed' effects as follows `dredge(fm, subset= re(1, herd) && re(1, obs))`, but this seems not to work. How would you configure `dredge` to keep only models containing 're(1, obs)' and `re(1, herd)`?

Comment: `dredge(fm, fixed = ~ re(1, herd) +  re(1, obs))`